# Sending data to LinkedIn Insight(Pixel and Conversion) via API?

Tags: linkedin-api

we are currently sending data to LinkedIn using client side. Recently our client migrated all the tracking to server side and is planning to do the same for LinkedIn insights. I have gone through the linkedIn page and didn't came across any API that can help(Even though the webpage says it support API). Talked to support and they mentioned to contact their partners.

Does anyone have an idea on how to send data to Linkedin insight via API's

I have gone through the linkedIn page and didn't came across any API that can help(Even though the webpage says it support API). Talked to support and they mentioned to contact their partners.